# How to import Thrift 0.12 into Xcode to support Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import, thrift

I am trying to set up a new project that supports Thrift 0.12 and Swift 4.2 in Xcode. In my swift files that were generated by Thrift, all of them have the line "import Thrift", but I get a compile error "No such module 'Thrift'". I am at a loss on how to resolve this issue. Importing Thrift as a cocoapod does not seem to work because the latest version I can download though a pod seems to be 0.10, which does not support Swift 4.2. I have Thrift 0.12 downloaded onto my mac, which is how I generated the thrift-to-swift files in the first place. Below is one of the generated files.

I have tried: 
`pod "Thrift"` and 
`pod 'Thrift-swift3', :git => 'git@github.com:apache/thrift.git', :branch => 'master'` 
Neither of them work.

My generated swift file:

```
import Foundation
import Thrift

public final class TTestMessage {

  public var title: String?
  public var message: String?

  public init() { }
  public init(title: String?, message: String?) {
    self.title = title
    self.message = message
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a PR for Swift 4.2+ compatibility (https://github.com/apache/thrift/pull/1827) and it was merged.

So a working solution is now the following in your Podfile:

```rb
pod 'Thrift', :git => 'git@github.com:apache/thrift.git'
```